# How to give permissions to chrome/mozilla camera programmatically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, camera, mozilla

I am running a code on browser using node server which requires camera. Every time I need to give permission to access the camera. Is there any way where

1. We can give permission to the node server running on particular port to access the camera or
2. We can give permission to the client (javascript) to access the camera?

Please help !  Thank you.

Have used navigator to give permission to camera, but I need a program which grants permission to access the camera in browser.

```
navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                             navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                             navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                             navigator.msGetUserMedia;
            navigator.getMedia({
                 video: true,
                 audio: false
             }, function(stream){
                    video.srcObject=stream;
                    video.play();  //to play video
            }, function(error){

               });
```

Comment: asking for help here without code will not be useful. Please share code

Comment: Hi Ronit, thanks for reply. I didn't get any method to grant permission for camera inside the code.

Comment: Code asks for permission not for granting permission. That's called permission if with code we grand permission then it's loss of security. With code, you have to ask for permission, then it's user's wish to give that permission or not.

Comment: But I am creating an application where there is no user intervention. User expects a camera there so I wanted this solution.